# Selenium Python XPATH I am trying to find the input tag which has some text in the title attribute

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a HTML page with some checkboxes with a name beside it.  Using XPATH I can locate the checkbox which has the complete text in the title attribute using = to match the complete text.
E.g.

```
//div[@id="operations_add_process_list_tab_groups_tab_standard_1"]//span//input[@title="CRM : crm"]
```

I don't want to match the whole text, I would like to find it by using some of the text e.g. I would like to find the checkbox where "CRM" in the title attribute.
I don't want to use "CRM : crm"

Can i use the contains keyword to find where "CRM" is in the title attribute?
I do not know the syntax for this.

I tried: `//div[@id="operations_add_process_list_tab_groups_tab_standard_1"]//span//input[@title[contains(text(), CRM : crm")]]`

The HTML is:

```
<div id="operations_add_process_list_tab_groups_tab_standard_1">
<span>
<span>
<span/>
<span>
<span/>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="" title="CRM : crm" tabindex="-1"/>
    CRM : crm
</span>
</span>
<span>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="" title="ESCR : escr" tabindex="-1"/>
    ESCR : escr
</span>
</span>
<span>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="" title="ORCHARD : orchard" tabindex="-1"/>
    ORCHARD : orchard
</span>
</span>
```

Thanks,
Riaz

Comment: Try `//div[@id="operations_add_process_list_tab_groups_tab_standard_1"]//span//input[contains(@title, "CRM : crm")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contains` is what you are looking for. In your case.

```
//input‌​[contains(@title, "CRM")]
```

`contains` can be used for any attribute and for text in the element as well.